# Search Query returns only 50000 Events/Results List of 5.6 million events

Tags: splunk

Observing an issue while I try to query the Splunk for
search query returns only 50000 events/results list totally though total events/results are almost 5.6 million events.

What settings do I need to make in any of the Splunk configuration files?

#### Example of what I tried:

I tried below for lessers Mails, around 1.6 million Events/Results: (but no luck)

```
vm30esa0072:rtestuser 116] /data/third_party/splunk/bin/splunk dispatch "* starttime=04/11/2017:00:00:00 endtime=04/12/2017:23:59:00 | stats count" -auth admin:changeme
count
1686815
```

Totally there are 1.6 million around events/results in the Splunk DB. But get only 50K Results!

**limits.conf file snippet:**

Comment: Just as an FYI, Lakh is not a word that exists outside of India as far as I am aware. It's "hundred thousand" in America and probably elsewhere as well. This note is as much for OP as for anyone else trying to read the question.

Comment: Also, you are missing the advertised snippet.

Comment: What does your limits.conf look like?